# Customisation of Drawer Width Material Desgin Bootsrap

Tags: bootstrap-material-design

I am finding it hard to understand the Following :

Globally, you may alter the size of x vs y drawers with the following variables:

$bmd-drawer-x-size
$bmd-drawer-y-size

What does it mean ? I am refering to the Following Link. 
[http://rosskevin.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/material-design/drawers/#customization.](http://rosskevin.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/material-design/drawers/#customization)

> All i want to achieve is to increase the Size of the Drawer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can increase the size of left, right (horizontal) drawers using `$bmd-drawer-x-size` and top, bottom (vertical) drawers using `$bmd-drawer-y-size`.

You need to edit the SASS variable and update it, or override it from different file